# Changing text of label does not work

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with the following python script. Later, it will catch the data from a barcode scanner and display the text as a label. But whenever the text should be changed from the label (highlighted line), the program crashes. I am an absolute beginner Python and can not explain that. I comment out the line, the program works.

```
from Tkinter import *
import pyHook

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Sc4nn0r")
        self.variable = "Start Variable"

        self.master.geometry("363x200")
        self.master.resizable(0,0)

        self.master.rowconfigure( 0, weight = 1)
        self.master.columnconfigure( 0, weight = 1 )
        self.grid( sticky = W+E+N+S )

        self.label4String = StringVar()
        self.label4 = Label(self, textvariable=self.label4String)
        self.label4.grid( row = 2, column = 1, columnspan = 2, sticky = W+E+N+S)
        self.label4String.set("Variable1")

        self.string = ''
        hook = pyHook.HookManager()
        hook.KeyDown = self.read
        hook.HookKeyboard()

    def read(self, event):
        print(event.Ascii);
        if event.Ascii != 13:
            self.string = self.string + chr(event.Ascii)
        else:
            self.post(self.string.strip(' \0'))
            self.string = ''
        return True

    def post(self,string):
        self.label4String.set(string) # THIS LINE I Mean ##########
        print(string)


def main():
    Application().mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I hope it can someone help me.

Comment: Works on my machine. Exactly what actions are you taking to cause the crash?

Comment: When I enter a string and press return, the method "self.post" is called and output the string to the console. But if the line "self.label4String.set (string)" is not commented out, it works no second time. I can not enter any characters (nothing happens). I can not quit them program on "X" also. I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Strange. I wonder if it has anything to do with Tkinter's habitual incompatibility with threaded applications. If the KeyDown callback is executed outside of the main thread, then you might see weird and unexpected behavior.

Comment: Why are you using pyHook rather than Tkinter's event handler?

Comment: I must capture the keyboard events from another program window.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting rid of StringVar in its entirety. Instead, use `self.label4 = Label(self, text = "Variable1")`. Then, whenever you wish to change the label, you can use `self.label4.config(text = string)`.

Comment: That's what I tried first and it had the same effect.

Comment: In that case may we see the original implementation as well?